# Haskell. From pure code to IO and back

Tags: haskell, recursion, io

Are there a possibility to stop a recursive algorithm when it throws some exception provided by us, save it's state, ask user something and then continue the recursion from the saved place?

I changed the question.

I read a file system recursively and keep data in a tree. Suddenly I face with a hidden directory. Can I stop calculations and ask now user should I place information about the directory in my tree and then continue calculations?

About working with IO:

```
obtainTree :: ByteString -> Tree
...
main = print $ obtainTree partition
```

as I understand to work with IO inside the algorithm we have to use function like this:

```
obtainTree :: ByteString -> IO Tree
```

but can we avoid it?

Comment: It's difficult to answer your question without code.

Comment: What, how are you reading the file system to build up the tree if you're not already in the IO monad?

Comment: i've added code to the question to illustrate

Comment: Is there a good reason to avoid giving `obtainTree` the type `ByteString -> IO Tree`?

Comment: @DanielWagner I think the assumption is that the `ByteString` contains all needed information, it should be possible to do this without IO and retain the nice referential transparency and ease of testing. Actually this is a poster child for control.monad.prompt

Comment: @jozefg If you have to interact with the user, why believe that it can be done without IO?

Comment: @DanielWagner You can mock it out to be a constant thing (always return ignore or whatever) and it can be tested and used in pure code. You can even think of this as just leaving the parser open to configuration

Comment: @jozefg Okay, that's a good reason, and there's techniques to handle that. But if it's all the same, I'd like to hear Leonidas' reasons -- so that we pick techniques that match his reason, and so that we can say "just use IO" if he doesn't have one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing first, a pure code cannot go to IO or we can say a pure function needs to become impure if it tries to use some impure function (i.e trying to use IO). In case you are wondering why this so, think about this: If the pure function ask the impure function about some data to complete its own processing then it looses "Referential transparency" because now the pure function can return different result for same input due to the involved impure (IO) call, hence it is no more pure.

Based on the above information, your solution will be as simple as making use of higher order function to ask the user about the information. Something like:

`parseFileSystem :: FileSystem -> (Directory -> IO Tree) -> IO Tree`

Here the `(Directory -> IO Tree)` is the function that will ask user about the required information and return a `Tree` data based on it.

Answer (score 6):

Sure you can do it. You can always set things up so that you capture the remaining computation as a continuation, which can be resumed externally.

Here's one way to do something like this:

```
-- intended to be put in a module that only exports the following list:
-- (Resumable, Prompted, prompt, runResumable, extract, resume)
import Control.Applicative

newtype Resumable e r a = R { runResumable :: Either (Prompted e r a) a }

data Prompted e r a = P e (r -> Resumable e r a)

suspend :: e -> (r -> Resumable e r a) -> Resumable e r a
suspend e = R . Left . P e

instance Functor (Resumable e r) where
    fmap f (R (Right x)) = pure $ f x
    fmap f (R (Left (P e g))) = suspend e $ \x -> f <$> g x

instance Applicative (Resumable e r) where
    pure = R . Right
    (R (Right f)) <*> (R (Right x)) = pure $ f x
    (R (Left (P e f))) <*> x = suspend e $ \y -> f y <*> x
    f <*> (R (Left (P e g))) = suspend e $ \y -> f <*> g y

instance Monad (Resumable e r) where
    return = pure
    (R (Right x)) >>= f = f x
    (R (Left (P e f))) >>= g = suspend e $ \x -> f x >>= g


prompt :: e -> Resumable e r r
prompt e = suspend e pure

extract :: Prompted e r a -> e
extract (P e _) = e

resume :: Prompted e r a -> r -> Either (Prompted e r a) a
resume (P _ f) e = runResumable $ f e
```

This lets you divide up your logic into an internal piece that runs inside `Resumable` and an external piece that handles the results of the internal part's prompting using whatever method it likes.

Here's a simple example of using this:

```
askAboutNegatives :: [Int] -> Resumable Int Bool [Int]
askAboutNegatives [] = return []
askAboutNegatives (x:xs) = do
    keep <- if x < 0 then prompt x else return True
    rest <- askAboutNegatives xs
    return $ if keep then x:rest else rest

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let ls = [1, -4, 2, -7, 3]
        loopIfNeeded (Right r) = return r
        loopIfNeeded (Left p) = do
            putStrLn $ "Would you like to keep " ++ show (extract p)
            i <- getLine
            loopIfNeeded $ resume p (i == "y")
    asked <- loopIfNeeded $ runResumable (askAboutNegatives ls)
    print asked
```

As a way of making this use case simpler, the module containing `Resumable` can be augmented to also export this function:

```
runResumableWithM :: Monad m => (e -> m r) -> Resumable e r a -> m a
runResumableWithM f x = case runResumable x of
    Right y -> return y
    Left (P e g) -> do
        r <- f e
        runResumableWithM f $ g r
```

Which would allow rewriting `main` from that example as the somewhat simpler:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let ls = [1, -4, 2, -7, 3]
        ask x = do
            putStrLn $ "Would you like to keep " ++ show x
            i <- getLine
            return $ i == "y"
    asked <- runResumableWithM ask (askAboutNegatives ls)
    print asked
```

The one real issue with this approach is that every prompt must have the same type. Otherwise, it handles the problem nicely, using continuations to capture the rest of the computation implicitly when needed.

Comment: I get it. I must totally change the question.

Comment: @Leonidas Please post a new question rather than completely redo this one, it makes all of Carl's hard work for nothing and is useless to future visiters :)

Comment: @jozefg Fortunately, all the hard work I was doing was actually anticipating that edit. :)

Comment: But if I read FS, I'll have to collect information about state of my algorithm in a structure named 'r' here, isn't it? In this case it will take too much memory, and it will repeat what already exists there.

Comment: @Leonidas Is that question asked before or after I added the examples?

Comment: before. but does it solve the problem? If we work with function like: foo = let something = ... in something ++ foo, on every new stage the tree of recursion will become bigger, and we have to save the whole tree consisting of all this 'something'? Or I don't understand?

Comment: It will be as big as it needs to be. If it makes a slightly-modified copy of another data structure, yes, it will need to make the copy. Though if it consumes the original carefully, it might be able to garbage collect parts as soon as they've been processed. If your goal is separate passes as much as possible, this is close to the best you'll manage. If your goal is to minimize garbage production, then you have to do the prompting as part of the initial tree construction. Since both are in IO, that means the result will also be in IO.

Comment: Note that this type is a free monad in disguise.  If you define `data Prompted e r x = P e (r -> x)` instead, then `type Resumable e r = Free (Prompted e r)`.